# double slash for xpath. Selenium Java Webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver. I have a doubt about the xpath.

If I have the following code example:

```
<div>
     <div>
           <div>
                 <a>
                      <div>
                      </div>
                 </a>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And I want to locate the element which is in the last `<div>`. I think I have 2 options with the xpath.

First option is with single slash:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/div/div/div/a/div")).click();
```

Second option is using double slash (and here is where I have the doubt).

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/div")).click();
```

Is it going to search in the `<a>` directly, but what happens if the html example code was just a part of a bigger code and in this bigger code are more "`<a>`"?. Where would this method look exactly?

What happens for example if I do it like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div")).click();
```

Would it looks if every `<div>` found in the html code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, avoiding `//` is usually the right thing to do - so, the first expression you show is perfect.

> Would it looks if every `<div>` found in the html code?

Yes, exactly. An XPath expression like

```
//div
```

will select *all* `div` elements in the document, regardless of where they are.

> what happens if the html example code was just a part of a bigger code and in this bigger code are more `<a>`?. Where would this method look exactly?

Then, let us make the HTML "bigger":

```
<div>
     <a>
         <p>C</p>
     </a>
     <div>
           <div>
                 <a>
                      <div>A</div>
                 </a>
           </div>
           <a>
               <div>B</div>
           </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have added two more `a` elements - only one of them contains a `div` element. Assuming this new document as the input, there will now be a difference between

```
/div/div/div/a/div
```

which will select *only* `<div>A</div>` as the result, and

```
//a/div
```

which will select both `<div>A</div>` and `<div>B</div>` - because the exact position of `a` in the tree is now irrelevant. But none of them will select the first `a` element that contains `p`.