# How to prevent Selenium Webdriver adding double slash in driver.get() url in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver to get an internal corporate web page, which is a search form. 
My code will successfully open a browser and pull up the target page, but there is an unwanted double slash in the url which affects subsequent search form behavior.

Instead of showing 'http://example.web.company.com/directory/subdirectory/target_page.cfm' 
I get: 'http://example.web.company.com//directory/subdirectory/target_page.cfm'

Note double slash after ".com". Does anyone know how/why the extra slash is inserted, and how I can prevent it?

This is somewhat complicated because I have to execute an internal login before the browser will open the page. It redirects to the login, fill in the prompts, and then the code below will load the requested page successfully. It just brings up the double slash version.

```
import getpass
import requests, lxml.html 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Get user input credentials
user = input('Enter ID: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')

# Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Drivers\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe') 

# Target web page
driver.get('http://example.web.company.com/directory/subdirectory/target_page.cfm')

# Navigate Logon Page 
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('ID')
elem.send_keys(user)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('PASSWORD')
elem.send_keys(password)
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('Submit')
elem.click()
```

If I then try to execute code to search for something using the web form, the double slash url version will successfully display a list of results for a partial-matched search term (normal behavior). But if I enter an exact (valid) search term, I get an error, which I guess seems to have to do with relative linking. But I don't have control over those pages, I'm just a user.

```
# Search routine from page returned above
item = input('SEARCH TERM: ')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('search_name')
elem.send_keys(item)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

This site provided some background on single and double slash urls and relative linking: https://sitebulb.com/hints/internal/url-contains-a-double-slash/

These stackoverflow threads touch on webdriver and driver.get(), but I wasn't able to find an answer to the question: Where does the extra slash come from and how to prevent it?

- [double slash for xpath. Selenium Java Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938820/double-slash-for-xpath-selenium-java-webdriver)
- [Selenium driver.get() modifying URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099403/selenium-driver-get-modifying-url)

Comment: You think your code is adding the `//`?

Comment: It really sounds like a bug on the server-side... when you browse manually does it happen?

Comment: I don't necessarily think it's my code doing it. It probably is something on the server side, in the login page/redirect sequence. It does not happen when I browse manually. I was just hoping that someone might know exactly what was happening and could hopefully show me a remedy that I could implement in my own code, which would be easier than reaching out to corporate overlords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually learned that the target result page is not accessible by automation under the same directory path that works manually. But there is another directory tree that does work with automation, and both touch the same database.

I cannot make my code work using the original target search site (because it only attempts the directory path that will not work with automation). But I am able use other loopable code to link to target results using the directory tree that does work.

I don't know exactly why the automation won't accept the same path that works manually, but I have a consistent workaround. I believe the issue with the double slash is not relevant.